# FFmpeg saturates memory + CPU usage drops to 0% during very basic conversion of PNG files to MP4 video

Tags: python, memory, video, ffmpeg, png

I have this Python function that runs `ffmpeg` with minimal options from the Windows command line:

```py
def run_ffmpeg(frames_path, ffmpeg_path=notebook_directory):
    '''
    This function runs ffmpeg.exe to convert PNG image files into a MP4 video.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    frames_path : string
        Absolute path to the PNG files
    ffmpeg_path : string
        Absolute path to the FFmpeg executable (ffmpeg.exe)
    '''
    
    from subprocess import check_call
    
    
    check_call(
        [
            os.path.join(ffmpeg_path, 'ffmpeg'),
            '-y',    # Overwrite output files without asking
            '-report',    # Write logfile to current working directory
            '-framerate', '60',    # Input frame rate
            '-i', os.path.join(frames_path, 'frame%05d.png'),    # Path to input frames
            os.path.join(frames_path, 'video.mp4')    # Path to store output video
        ]
    )
```

When running it from a Jupyter notebook over 2500 PNG files (RGBA, ca. 600-700 kB each, 9000 x 13934 pixels), CPU usage briefly peaks to 100% before dropping to 0%, while memory usage quickly saturates to 100% and stays there, slowing the system down almost to a freeze, so I need to terminate `ffmpeg` from the task manager:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k43C.png)

The generated video file has a size of only 48 bytes and contains just a black frame when viewed in the VLC player.

This is the `ffmpeg` log output:

```
ffmpeg started on 2022-08-05 at 17:17:55
Report written to "ffmpeg-20220805-171755.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
"C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\folder\\ffmpeg" -y -report -framerate 60 -i "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\e\\frame%05d.png" "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\e\\video.mp4"
ffmpeg version 2022-07-14-git-882aac99d2-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --ena  libavutil      57. 29.100 / 57. 29.100
  libavcodec     59. 38.100 / 59. 38.100
  libavformat    59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100
  libavdevice    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavfilter     8. 45.100 /  8. 45.100
  libswscale      6.  8.100 /  6.  8.100
  libswresample   4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '60'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame%05d.png'.
Reading option 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\video.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame%05d.png.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame%05d.png.
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00000.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000425680] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042d800] Statistics: 668318 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00001.png' for reading
[file @ 000000000042dac0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042d6c0] Statistics: 668371 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00002.png' for reading
[file @ 000000000042d6c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042dac0] Statistics: 669177 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00003.png' for reading
[file @ 000000000042dac0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000000437a40] Statistics: 684594 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00004.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000437a40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000000437c00] Statistics: 703014 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00005.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000437c00] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000000437d00] Statistics: 721604 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00006.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000437cc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000000437f40] Statistics: 739761 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00007.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000437f40] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 0000000000438040] Statistics: 757327 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Probe buffer size limit of 5000000 bytes reached
Input #0, image2, from 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame%05d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:41.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0, 8, 1/60: Video: png, rgba(pc), 9000x13934 [SAR 29528:29528 DAR 4500:6967], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\video.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\video.mp4.
[file @ 000000002081e3c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 12 logical cores
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00008.png' for reading
[file @ 00000000024ad980] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 00000000004379c0] Statistics: 767857 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00009.png' for reading
[file @ 000000000042d600] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 00000000004379c0] Statistics: 774848 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00010.png' for reading
[file @ 00000000004379c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042da00] Statistics: 787178 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00011.png' for reading
[file @ 00000000004379c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042da00] Statistics: 797084 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00012.png' for reading
[file @ 0000000000437a80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000042da00] Statistics: 802870 bytes read, 0 seeks
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] Setting 'video_size' to value '9000x13934'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '26'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/60'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '29528/29528'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '60/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000208bf800] w:9000 h:13934 pixfmt:rgba tb:1/60 fr:60/1 sar:29528/29528
[format @ 00000000025ef840] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p|yuvj420p|yuv422p|yuvj422p|yuv444p|yuvj444p|nv12|nv16|nv21|yuv420p10le|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|nv20le|gray|gray10le'
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[format @ 00000000025ef840] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000000000042da00] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] picking yuv444p out of 13 ref:rgba alpha:1
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] w:9000 h:13934 fmt:rgba sar:29528/29528 -> w:9000 h:13934 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x0
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] w:9000 h:13934 fmt:rgba sar:29528/29528 -> w:9000 h:13934 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x0
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] w:9000 h:13934 fmt:rgba sar:29528/29528 -> w:9000 h:13934 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x0
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000000025efe40] w:9000 h:13934 fmt:rgba sar:29528/29528 -> w:9000 h:13934 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x0
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] using mv_range_thread = 376
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] frame MB size (563x871) > level limit (139264)
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] DPB size (4 frames, 1961492 mbs) > level limit (1 frames, 696320 mbs)
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] MB rate (29422380) > level limit (16711680)
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 6.2, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000000002081d280] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.28.100
  Stream #0:0, 0, 1/15360: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 9000x13934 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4500:6967], q=2-31, 60 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.38.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.000008
frame=    1 fps=0.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00013.png' for reading
[file @ 000000000a6a2180] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 810395 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=    2 fps=0.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00014.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 818213 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00015.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 817936 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=    4 fps=1.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00016.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 817014 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00017.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 828088 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=    6 fps=1.5 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00018.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 831007 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00019.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 845203 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=    8 fps=1.7 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00020.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 851548 bytes read, 0 seeks
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00021.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 847629 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=   10 fps=1.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00022.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 860169 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=   11 fps=1.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00023.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 857243 bytes read, 0 seeks
frame=   12 fps=1.2 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[image2 @ 000000000041ff80] Opening 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\e\frame00024.png' for reading
[file @ 000000001ec86c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[AVIOContext @ 000000000b38de80] Statistics: 835155 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

What is the problem?

By the way, the color model of the image files was confirmed by doing

```
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\EPI-SMLM\\Desktop\\e\\frame00000.png')
img.mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:3035: DecompressionBombWarning: Image size (125406000 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
  warnings.warn(

'RGBA'
```

The "decompression bomb warning" appears to be a false alarm/bug.

**UPDATE:** I can confirm that this happens even when there are only 50 image files, i.e. *50 x 700 kB = 35 MB* in total size. `ffmpeg` still gobbles up all available memory (almost ***60 GB*** of private bytes!!!).

And it also happens if `ffmpeg` is run from the command line.

This must be a bug!

Comment: did you try to run `ffmpeg` directly in shell without `Python`?

Comment: @furas Yes, I did (see updated question) with the same result. I'm beginning to wonder if maybe the input image dimensions (9000 x 13934 pixels) are causing the problem

Comment: It has to be the image size. Remember that all frames are first decoded, meaning ffmpeg needs 358MB+ per frame buffer (assuming 24 bits/px) not 700 kB/frame you mentioned above. Knowing ffmpeg has frame queues (both at demuxer and muxer) I can see ffmpeg max out memory allocation with hi-res video. Wonder if you can play with `-thread_queue_size` and other buffering related options to prevent your issue.

Comment: @kesh Hi, I agree, this is definitely related to some frame size limitations. But how come that a 700 kB PNG image frame requires over 350 MB frame buffer?? Could you explain where and how this factor of ***500x*** is introduced?

Comment: if one pixel occupies 3 bytes = 24 bits (say 8 bits per red, green, & blue) then one frame requires: width x height x bpp = 9000 x 13934 x 3 = 376,218,000 bytes = 359 MB. I don't know the nature of your image, but image/video compression algorithms work really well when there is easily predictable patterns in your image.

Comment: Just save your PNG file as BMP file and you'll see how big it gets. That's how much memory you'll need per frame at each stage of transcoding.

Comment: @kesh Thanks for the explanation. But how can it be that such images (i.e. 9000 px * 13934 px * 3 bytes for RGB24 or even 9000 x 13934 x 4 bytes for RGB32) can take only ~700 kB per image on disk? That's the point I can't wrap my head around...are my images in some way compressed? They are "normal" PNG output images generated by `matplotlib`, so RGBA plot figures (although what's shown aren't just graphs, but propagating electromagnetic fields)

Comment: See if [this link](https://compress-or-die.com/Understanding-PNG) helps

Comment: What is the output video for? If it's for a presentation purpose (not for archiving), you'd only need 4K (3840 x 2160) at max. No 99% of display devices today are 4K or less, Even downscaling (`-s -2x2160` output option) may help your transcoding.

Comment: I'm simulating the propagation of EM fields, where every N simulation steps, `matplotlib` will save a snapshot of the field distribution as a PNG plot figure. As the data is inherently dynamic, animating the image stack into a movie is a straightforward step for visualization. The pixel dimension result from a choice of DPI in `matplotlib` which allows for an image resolution very close to the "mesh size" of the simulation grid - which in this example has a height of 10000 grid cells. Add to this the automatic whitespace padding of `matplotlib` in width and you end up with these huge images ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement/addendum/update to the other answer provided: It appears that setting the profile to `high444` instead of the default `medium` (just `high` doesn't work!) and increasing the H.264 level to the highest possible value `6.2` is successful in preventing memory leaks.

The problem seems to be a bug of `ffmpeg`, where reading in images with a resolution higher than the [max. specified resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Levels) of whatever H.264 level currently set will lead to an unbounded memory leak and possibly system freeze/crash.

Limiting the resolution using the `scale` filter to the max. specified value for the set H.264 level and/or increasing said level seems to solve the problem. I still get 100% CPU and RAM usage, but `ffmpeg` now pulls through and finishes with 0 status.

The output MP4 video resulting from a 10-20 GB/2000-3000 frames input of PNG image files has a size of only 2-3 MB.

```
check_call(
    [
        os.path.join(ffmpeg_path, 'ffmpeg'),
        '-y',    # Overwrite output files without asking
        '-report',    # Write logfile to current working directory
        '-framerate', '60',    # Input frame rate
        '-i', os.path.join(frames_path, 'frame%05d.png'),    # Path to input frames
        '-profile:v', 'high444',
        '-level:v', '6.2',
        '-bsf:v', 'h264_metadata=level=6.2',
        #'-vf', 'scale=4096:-1',    # Scale width or height down to max. 4096x2304 while keeping aspect ratio (H.264 level 5.2)
        #'-vf', 'scale=-1:2304',    # Scale width or height down to max. 4096x2304 while keeping aspect ratio (H.264 level 5.2)
        #'-vf', 'scale=8192:-1',    # Scale width or height down to max. 4096x2304 while keeping aspect ratio (H.264 level 6.2)
        '-vf', 'scale=-1:4320',    # Scale width or height down to max. 4096x2304 while keeping aspect ratio (H.264 level 6.2)
        os.path.join(frames_path, 'video.mp4')    # Path to store output video
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can confirm that this happens even when there are only 50 image files, i.e. 50 x 700 kB = 35 MB in total size. ffmpeg still gobbles up all available memory (almost 60 GB of private bytes!!!). [..] This must be a bug!

Let's calculate! When using RGB input, we use YUV444/RGB encoding using x264. This will use a frame queue of all 50 frames for rate control purposes, each 3 bytes/pixel, so total memory usage = 3x9000x14000x50=~19GB just for the images alone. Inside the RC (rate control; specifically, the lookahead queue), these images will have several chunks of per-block metadata associated with them like MVs and complexity graphs, so a multiplier of 3 is not so strange for this situation. 60GB? Sure, that's expected. In my local quick experiments, that's indeed what's happening (and it's easily prevented).

The problem is that you're encoding extremely high resolution images (9kx14k! Typical video res is 2k/HD = 2kx1k; 4k/UHD = 4kx2k is considered extremely high resolution, and almost nobody uses 8K = 8kx4k at this point) using a production encoder at production settings. What you probably want to do is one or more of the following:

- downscale images to yuv420p and lower resolution (e.g. 1000x1556 pixels or so: `-vf scale=1000:-1`, possibly combined with `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) - just `-vf scale=1000:-1` makes it use 2.75GB memory for me
- use low-latency encoding (`-tune zerolatency`) to reduce number of frames in queue (this uses ~10GB memory for me at 9k*14k resolution).
- use a high-end server that is suitable for high-def video encoding, e.g. one with several 100s of GB of memory and several 10s of cores for CPU processing.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `RC` and am I correct that `-tune zerolatency` goes "into the output section" (i.e. somewhere *after* the input URI)? Thx

Comment: Also, I've read somewhere on SO/SE that using `-rc-lookahead', '6'` can further reduce memory usage. Do you maybe know this option and would you agree that this works? Or does this apply only for decoding a video stream as input (not individual image files)?

Comment: ...I just tested you suggestion of using `-tune zerolatency`. Without this option, `ffmpeg` takes abou 90 seconds to finish, while with this option it takes only around 60 seconds. More importantly, having this option on halved the bitrate and consequently also the output video file size from about 1.7 MB down to only about 900 kB. **Is this expected behavior?** Would you expect the opposite, i.e. a smaller file with `zerolatency` switched *ON* (lower quality for the price of reduced CPU/RAM load)?

Comment: ...the final video resolution is the same, btw - is chroma subsampling responsible for the reduction (even though the profile was set to `high444` in both cases)?

Comment: The file size is lower because the quality is lower. For example, if you measure input vs. output PSNR (`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -f image2 -i file%05d.png -i file.mp4 -lavfi psnr -v info -`), I'd expect the lower-bitrate file to have a lower objective quality score.

Comment: In terms of stuff that's relevant for your problem, `-tune zerolatency` is something akin to `-rc-lookahead 1`, so the two are similar in intent.

Comment: So does `-tune zerolatency` effectively tune the `-rc-lookahead` value, i.e. can both options really be used interchangeably?

Comment: Also, there is an error in my comment above: Please note that *using* `-tune zerolatency` took *90 seconds*, while **not** using `zerolatency` took only *60 seconds*!* Does this mean that this option basically "spreads" the reading of image frames over a longer processing time, thus reducing RAM pressure? Is this the correct description?

Comment: FYI, here is some of the `ffmpeg` log output with `zerolatency` turnen **ON**: *"options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 **lookahead_threads=12** sliced_threads=1 slices=12 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf"*

Comment: Now with `zerolatency` turned **OFF**: *"options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=18 **lookahead_threads=3** sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 **rc_lookahead=40**"*

Comment: As you suggested, without `zerolatency` the `rc_lookahead` defaults to a high value of `40`. However, with `zerolatency` on this option is missing altogether, which begs the question: Through what other option has `ffmpeg` reduced `rc-lookahead`?